# Which data type cannot be thrown as exception in a c++ program

Tags: c++, exception

One can throw exception of type int,float,long or custom data types like classes and structs. But which data type can't be thrown as exception in C++?

Comment: Abstract types, (pointers to) incomplete types and types without accesible copy/move constructor. I think that covers everything.

Comment: You can throw arrays, but they decay to pointer to their first element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exception **can not** throw incomplete type:

§ 15.1

> If the temporary is an lvalue and is used to initialize the variable named in the matching handler (15.3). **If the type of the exception object would be an incomplete type or a pointer to an incomplete type other than (possibly cv-qualified) void the program is ill-formed.** Except for these restrictions and the restrictions on type matching mentioned in 15.3, the operand of throw is treated exactly as a function argument in a call (5.2.2) or the operand of a return statement.

§ 15.5

> When the thrown object is a class object, the copy/move constructor and the destructor shall be accessible, even if the copy/move operation is elided (12.8).

15.3.1  Handling an exception

The exception-declaration in a handler describes the type(s) of exceptions that can cause that handler to be entered. **The exception-declaration shall not denote an incomplete type or an rvalue reference type. The exception-declaration shall not denote a pointer or reference to an incomplete type, other than void*, const void*, volatile void*, or const volatile void*.**

Comment: 15.1/5 is relevant, too.

Comment: Thanks jrok, you should make your comment as an answer!